# Should products with "Apple" in their name have a dash?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should a product name using "Apple" (ex. Apple Watch, Apple Music, Apple TV) have a dash between the word "Apple" and the other word?

I have noticed a difference between the tags [apple-watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) and [appletv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appletv).

Should we rename [apple-watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) to [applewatch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applewatch) to fit [appletv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appletv) or should we rename [appletv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appletv) to [apple-tv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-tv) to fit [apple-watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the site, spaces in official product names are represented by ‘-’ in tag names, therefore [appletv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appletv) should be [apple-tv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-tv), leaving [apple-watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch)/etc as they currently are.